# Gauss formula to calculate integral

Tags: integration, divergence-theorem

Using Gauss formula calculate:$\int_S x^3dydz+y^3dxdz+z^2dxdy$ where $S$ is down part of $z=x^2+y^2$ cut out with plane $z=2x$. Using divergence theorem it comes to find:$\iiint_D (3x^2+3y^2+2z)dxdydz$, where $D$ is area bounded with(after cylindrical coordinates) $-\frac{\pi}{2}\le \phi\le \frac{\pi}{2}, 0\le r\le 2\cos\phi, 2r\cos\phi\le z\le r^2$. What is left is to plug in formula. Correct?

Comment: You surface $S$ is not a closed surface, and you didn't state how the surface is oriented. Is the normal vector pointing up or down?

Comment: To clarify: Is the surface the boundary of that region, or is it just the portion of the paraboloid? If the latter, you have to compute the flux across the planar region by hand and adjust your triple integral accordingly. And, yes, orientation.

Comment: Should I calculate this using line integral(second kind)?

Comment: You can only use Stokes's Theorem if the vector field is the curl of another vector field? Could it be?

Comment: Well, it is not said. It is only written that it is bottom part of paraboloid cut out by plane

Comment: OK, and what would be other way?

Comment: Let $S_1$ denote the surface of the plane $z=2x$ on domain $(x-1)^2+y^2 \leq 1$ oriented upward, $S_2$ denote the surface of the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$ on domain $(x-1)^2 +y^2 \leq 1$ oriented downward, and let be $E$ be the solid defined by the region of space below $S_1$ and above $S_2$. Gauss' Theorem says

$$\iiint_{E}\text{div}(F)dV=\iint_{S_1}\big(F\cdot n\big)dS+\iint_{S_2}\big(F\cdot n\big)dS$$ You're trying to compute $\iint_{S_2}\big(F\cdot n\big)dS$ which means you have to calculate both integrals $\iint_{S_1}\big(F\cdot n\big)dS$ and $\iiint_{E}\text{div}(F)dV$ directly.

Comment: Not sure really. I don't think I understand why are we substracting flux of plane. For the bounds, yes my bad.

Comment: OK so divergence theorem gives outward flux through a closed surface. In this case it will include the top. What we are interested in is to find the flux only through the paraboloid surface that is cut out by the plane. So if we find the flux through the top surface, we can subtract it from what we got from divergence theorem. That is flux through the paraboloid surface. Other way is to directly find flux through the paraboloid surface using surface integral without applying divergence theorem.

Comment: OK, and in that case(with surface integral) I am doing dot product between vector field and normal, right? Bounds are same, just here we don't have $z$?

Comment: Yes we do dot product with normal vector. I will update in sometime. Hopefully that will help. But always remember to check whether the surface is closed or not when applying divergence theorem. It is very important and always check the orientation. If you find flux through the plane with wrong orientation, you will get wrong sign and then if you subtract from the answer from triple integral, you would instead of subtracting, would have erroneously added flux to it.

Comment: OK, i think it is easier with surface integral. I will take care about that next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will go ahead and show all three and how we choose right orientation for different integrals so they are in sync with each another. Hope this helps for future questions too. I think you already did the first two integrals.

a) By applying divergence theorem which you already did,

Divergence = $3(x^2+y^2)+2z = 3r^2 + 2z$ in cylindrical coordinates,

$\displaystyle \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{2\cos\theta} \int_{r^2}^{2r\cos\theta} (3r^2 + 2z) \ r \ dz \ dr \ d\theta = \frac{11\pi}{3}$

This is flux for positively oriented surface (outward normal vector).

b) Flux through paraboloid surface (surface integral, without applying divergence theorem), which again you mentioned you knew how to find.

Surface is $z - x^2 - y^2 = 0$, taking derivative, normal vector $(2x, 2y, -1)$ or $(-2x, -2y, 1)$. The question does not state but since here we assume outward normal vector as in (a), that would be pointing generally downward for paraboloid surface $z = x^2+y^2$. Hence we choose $(2x, 2y, -1)$ - note the sign of $z$ component.

$\vec{F} = (x^3,y^3,z^2),$ so $\vec{F} \cdot \vec{n} = 2(x^4+y^2) - (x^2+y^2)^2$ (as on the paraboloid surface $z = x^2 + y^2$)

Simplifying, $\vec{F} \cdot \vec{n} = (x^2-y^2)^2$. Now the projection of paraboloid surface in $XY$ plane is the intersection of the plane and the paraboloid which is $x^2+y^2 = 2x$. In cylindrical coordinates the surface integral becomes,

$\displaystyle \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{2\cos\theta} r^4 \cos^2(2\theta) r dr d\theta = \frac{13\pi}{6}$.

c) Flux through the planar surface on top

Plane is $z = 2x$ and hence normal vector is $(2,0,-1)$ or $(-2, 0, 1)$. As we are finding flux for outward normal, in this case, the normal vector will be pointing upward in positive $z$ direction. So we choose $(-2, 0, 1)$.

Again $\vec{F} \cdot \vec{n} = (x^3,y^3,z^2) \cdot (-2, 0, 1) = 4x^2 - 2x^3$ (as on the plane, $z = 2x$). In cylindrical coordinates, the integral becomes,

$\displaystyle \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{2\cos\theta} (4r^2 \cos^2\theta - 2r^3 \cos^3 \theta) \ r \ dr \ d\theta = \frac{3\pi}{2}$

**Now for this question, if you are not mandated to use Divergence theorem, you can go with $(b)$ as it is more straightforward. But if you are asked to use Divergence theorem, you find $(a)$ and $(c)$ and then $(b) = (a) - (c)$.**

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is much easier to understand without divergence theorem. Honestly I didn't know conditions that need to be satisfied to use Gauss formula. All clear now.